# Split numbers from api with commas?

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request, 

urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://api.monzo.com/crowdfunding-investment/total"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

if 'invested_amount' in text:
    result = text.split(",")

invested = str(result[1])
investedn = invested.split(':')[1]

print(investedn)
```

Hi all. I’m trying to split investedn into thousands with commas. Anyone know how to do this?

Also, how can I remove the last four numbers from the string?

Thanks!

Comment: Post examples of the input and output you get and want.

Comment: For example an input might be 17462233620, and I'd like it to come out as £1,745,223. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix!

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://api.monzo.com/crowdfunding-investment/total"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

if 'invested_amount' in text:
    result = text.split(",")

invested = str(result[1])
investedn = invested.split(':')[1]
plainnum = int(str(investedn)[:-4])
number = "{:,}".format(int(plainnum))

print(number)
```

I had messed up quite a bit, but figured it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
"{:,}".format(number)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

e.g.

```
In [19]: "{:,}".format(17462233620)
Out[19]: '17,462,233,620'
```

Comment: This splits it, but it makes it seem as if its £17 million, not £1.7 million. Any way I can remove the numbers on the right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The text you got back from that URL is not HTML. It is data encoded in JSON format, which is easy to parse:

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = "https://api.monzo.com/crowdfunding-investment/total"
json_text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
json_text = json_text.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(json_text)
print(data)
print('Invested amount: {:,}'.format(data['invested_amount']))
```

Output:

```
{'invested_amount': 17529735495, 'share_price': 77145, 'shares_invested': 227231, 'max_shares': 2592520, 'max_amount': 199999955400, 'status': 'pending'}
Invested amount: 17,529,735,495
```

**Notes**

- `json_text` was an array of bytes, not a string. That is why I decode it using a guess of UTF-8.
- `data` is just a normal Python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I cleaned it up and used requests instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = "17462233620"
b = ""
for i in range(len(a), 0 , -3):
  b = a[i-3:i]+","+b
b = "£" + a[0:i] + b[:-1]
print(b) # Output £17,462,233,620
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it.

Comment: I have - I don’t think my votes appear though because I don’t have enough credit 